# Forced vibration single degree of freedom system

Tags: vibration, systems-engineering, frequency-response

so for the Single Degree of freedom system, I obtained the equation in blue, where I think the equation below in black is missing the ‘m*a’ from F=ma?

So I see that there is one ‘m*a’, but is that from the inertia or the F=ma?

Am I missing something here please? [image]

[image]

Comment: Blue equation has $m\ddot{x}$ on both sides of the $=$ sign. They will cancel out. Blue equation is probably wrong.

Comment: Hi, is that ‘m*a’ from the black equation please from the inertia of F=ma?

Comment: "*I obtained the equation in blue...*". Please show the steps by which you obtained the equation. Please use [edit] to add details directly into the question.

Answer (score 0):

The black equation is a rearranged form because $m\cdot a = m\cdot \ddot{x}$ (i.e. the acceleration is equation to the second derivative of position with respect to time) .

So (because positive is downwards) :
$$\sum_F = m\cdot a \rightarrow$$
$$-k\cdot x -c\cdot \dot{x} + F(t)= m\cdot \ddot{x}\rightarrow$$

Then rearranging and putting all $x$ related variables to the right side:

$$m\cdot \ddot{x}+ c\cdot \dot{x} +k\cdot x  = F(t) $$

The $F(t)$ is the external excitation force (the force that is applied and leads to the forced vibration).

Comment: Hi, so was I wrong? I thought that ‘m*a’ in the equation was from the mass inertia?

Comment: When representing $m\ddot{x}$ as a fictitious force you treat the system as if it is in static equilibrium, i.e. $\sum F=0$

Comment: @RonnyLandsverk since $\ddot{x}= a$ I would argue that I am using $\sum F = m\cdot a$

Comment: @NMech Google D'Alembert's principle. Your free-body-diagram has $m\ddot{x}$ on it. So you cannot use $\sum F=ma$.  You need to use $\sum F=0$

Comment: @NMech Btw, my first comment was intented for the OP and not specifically for your answer.